# Let $f(x)$ be polynomial in $R$. then «The only place where $f(\left| x \right|)$ might fail to have a derivative is the origin»

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be polynomial in $\mathbb{R}$.

Why The following  is true?

«The only place where $f(\left| x \right|)$ might fail to have a derivative is the origin»

Comment: For $x>0$, $f$ behaves locally like $x\mapsto f(x)$, and for $x<0$, $f$ behaves locally like $x\mapsto f(-x)$.

Comment: Also think about how the chain rule will work, it requires that the inner function, the absolute value to be differentiable at 0

Comment: Replace "Let $f$ be a polynomial" with "Let $f$ be a differentiable function defined in $\mathbb R$" for a more general result which will surely have pretty much the same solution as the presented problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being a polynomial $f(x)$ is derivable for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.$|x|$ is derivable in every point except for $0$, then their composition $f(|x|)$ is necessarily derivable in every point except for $0$, where it can either be or not.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that you have the absolute value bars in the wrong place from op

Comment: yes sorry.. bad typing

Comment: No problem just helping out